# How can I edit meta fields in multiple posts without database access?

Tags: wordpress, automation

I have 150 posts in my WordPress site that have a custom field value that I need to change. I do not have database access to make these changes and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas about how to automate this process?

The change I need to make is to change to urls from absolute to relative references. I am not sure how to approach automating this and any help getting me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thank You for your help!

Comment: This is impossible. If you don't have database access, from where do you plan on fetching and saving your new fields?

Comment: Do you have FTP access?

Comment: The current plan is to navigate in a browser to each post and edit the field values by hand. I am hoping to be able to find a way to automate some of this process so it goes a bit quicker.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible without FTP, Database Cpanel or Backend access. I'd spend your efforts on gaining access rather than a work around.

If you have administration access install [wp-dbmanager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dbmanager/) it will allow database table manipulation.

Without database access you could only write a plugin to do this or export specific tables and edit them then re-upload them with the plugin above.

Comment: I do not have the ability to install plugins for this, I'm in more of a super editor role on this site.